# How to tell a remote connection is in use without connecting to it?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, services

Me and a friend of mine are using a remote Windows 10 Professional machine together. Simultaneous remote connection are not supported, so every time I try to log in and he is logged in, I have to text him to get verification that he is not using it anymore and vice versa.

The Windows 10 Professional machine, his and my computer are all in the same LAN. It would be ideal to have some kind of command line tool to ping the remote computer and get information about the current session. Of course it makes no sense to get the same information that a remote connection attempt would provide

Heres my question, how would I set up a service that the operator of the remote PC can use to signal that he is still using the pc just by setting of a signal (maybe just a line in a text file, or a tick in a GUI, or a flag in a database). Which then can be pulled from either of us with our own computers.

I know that the amount of effort is not equal to the actual benefits a solution like that would provide.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to easily hack it, you could simply use taskscheduler to create a file called `yourusername.logged.on` inside a directory shared by FTP/other. Delete it at logoff via: [Scheduled log off task](https://qtechbabble.wordpress.com/2019/12/09/trigger-a-windows-scheduled-task-for-logoff/). This is probably the easiest way without creating your own dedicated service via python/.net or other.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could run the following PowerShell

`Get-WmiObject –ComputerName CLIENT1 –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName`

Comment: I have not used PowerShell before, could you give me a brief explanation?

Comment: Op's suggestion is good, this is one of those cool remote management powershell utilities, however it appears `Get-WmiObject` has been deprecated in PS-Core, and replaced by `Get-CimInstance`. I've tried to play around with it a bit but am unable to get it working locally, probably due to my Win userlicence. Try: `Get-CimInstance -ComputerName Client1 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName` and replace Client1 with your servers computernname, and ensure you are on the same workgroup/domain. Powershell should be installed by default.